# Enable or disable ngFor iterative elements

Tags: angular

I have following html code

```
 <canvas id="canvas{{i}}" #mycanvas width="550" heigth="650" (click)="onChartClick($event)" *ngIf="individualVisibility"></canvas>
```

This canvas is iterated in a for loop, multiple canvases are created. I want to enable only one and disable remaining canvases. I tried using ngIf, but it applies for all elements. 
In this case, can I create a custom directive and use it? Could any one provide suggestion.

I do not want to hide elements, basically I want those to be removed from DOM.

Comment: removing an element from DOM will remove it from view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display or hide canvas elements on click, you have to keep track of their visibility state.

In your component, create an array `visible` with same length as the iterable object used in `*ngFor`.

```
visible: boolean[];

// Initialize 'visible' array. 'collection' is the iterable object used in *ngFor.
this.visible = new Array(this.collection.length).fill(true);
```

Pass the index to canvas element's click event handler function.

```
<canvas *ngIf="visible[i]" id="canvas{{i}}" (click)="onChartClick(i)"></canvas>
```

Modify the click event handler function to only display selected canvas and remove others.

```
onChartClick(index) {
  this.visible = this.visible.map((value, i) => {
    if (i === index) {
      // Keep selected canvas visible.
      return true;
    } else {
      // Remove others.
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

Check out live demo on StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kshfid

Comment: Sorry my bad. I want to enable or disable canvas based on clicks. Suppose I have 4 canvas and I click on one of them that should be visible and remaining should be removed from dom.

Comment: @Vipul - Check out my edited answer. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: You should consider `return i === index` in your map, since that's all you're doing.

Comment: @Woohoojin - That's right, but I intentionally made it explicit to make it clear to the reader. Thanks for bringing it up.